# Capybara + Selenium + Firefox + Rails can not auto save file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, web-crawler, capybara

I have problem, I am trying to config auto save for my web crawler
   I am using Capybara + Selenium + Ruby + Firefox. Please take a look my code below:

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
  profile['browser.download.folderList'] = 2
  profile['browser.download.dir'] = "~/Downloads" 
  profile['browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force'] = false
  profile['browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting'] = false
  profile['browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile'] = "application/x-pdf, 
  application/acrobat, applications/vnd.pdf, text/pdf, text/x-pdf, 
  application/vnd.cups-pdf"
  profile['browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk'] = "application/x-pdf, 
  application/acrobat, applications/vnd.pdf, text/pdf, text/x-pdf, 
  application/vnd.cups-pdf"
  profile["pdfjs.disabled"] = true
  profile["browser.download.useDownloadDir"] = true
  profile["plugin.scan.plid.all"] = false
  profile["plugin.scan.Acrobat"] = "99.0"
  profile.native_events = true

  options = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Options.new(profile: profile)      
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :firefox, options: options)
end

Capybara.javascript_driver = :firefox
Capybara.configure do |config|  
  config.default_max_wait_time = 1000000
  config.default_driver = :selenium
end
```

But it seem not work

[Click here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3FM8.png)

Help me! Thank you so much!

Comment: Why are you setting `browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile` to the same mime types as `browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk` ??

Answer (score 0):

It's tough to say because you don't show how you're creating the actual session used in your app, but you're setting the javascript_driver to :firefox while configuring the profile in a driver called :selenium. If you're actually using the `javascript_driver` (:firefox) in your session then the profile would not be used.

Additionally, setting `browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile` and `browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk` to the same MIME types seems like they would be conflicting options.

Comment: Thank for you answer. If as you said, what favascript driver should be? But some options on profile is changing such as Download folder, only "profile['browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk']" not working.

Comment: Thank for you reply, but it still can not working. Do you have any documentations for this? Thanks